# How to reset an std::function?

Tags: c++, std-function

`std::function` can be empty, and it's convertible to `bool` to test if it has a target or not. But, how to set it to null after you've assigned something to it?

```
int main()
{
    std::function<void()> f = []() { return 4; };
    // how to reset to null, to it's initial state when default constructed.
}
```

Comment: But why would you want to set it to null?

Comment: @Irelia Same reason you'd set a pointer to null. Sometimes there's no function there. Why would there not be a function there? Why would there not be a valid address in a pointer? I don't know.

Comment: @JaMiT Resetting an std::function or setting it to "null" is not the same conceptually as assigning nullptr to it. It can hold an object separate from the pointer to the function call.

Comment: @JaMiT Oh OK, sorry. I'm surprised it doesn't have a reset function on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either:

- assign `nullptr` to it:

  ```
  f = nullptr;
  ```
- assign an empty `function` to it:

  ```
  f = std::function<void()>{};
  // or:
  f = decltype(f){};
  ```
- `swap()` it with another empty `function`:

  ```
  std::function<void()>{}.swap(f);
  // or:
  decltype(f){}.swap(f);
  ```

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way, I use it:

```
f = {};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hzEq3xo4e

```
#include <functional>

int main() {
  std::function<void()> f = []() { return 4; };
  f = {};
}
```

Comment: What syntax is that? Doing { }, what does it do exactly? Does it call the initialiser list constructor or what?

Comment: It calls `std::function::operator=(const std::function&)` with an empty temporary `std::function{}`, i.e. it assigns an empty `std::function` to an existing `std::function`, same as `f = decltype(f){};` but `decltype(f)` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

Assign `nullptr` to it to make it *empty*.

```
f = nullptr;
```